# Capturing image along with the frame

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am working with the custom camera, i have done basic functionality of taking picture and saving it in sd card. 
I want camera to come in the black space in the image below.
This has been done using surface view. 
But when Image is clicked,the frame doesn't come in the image clicked.

Can anybody suggest how to click image with the frame as in image below.
[image]

Here is my layout for preview screen for camera.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/frame" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_click"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/take_photo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://github.com/josnidhin/Android-Camera-Example

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar i have alrady use this but it does not help me in this problem.

Comment: so u want to create cousten camera

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar I already did this. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: @Amrit .. I am trying to implement the same functionality as you do. Have you got the solution?